# Perl, Compare two hashes - Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop, hash, foreach

Please bear with me, I've never asked a programming question on the internet, so I am not sure how to explain myself.  In any case, on with the questions.

My goal is to compare two hashes, each of which is the contents of a database, and update the local database's record of the remote database's entry where the value of the remote db's ident doesn't match local's record of ident, which is named unqiue_ident.

I currently have to update the local database's status to disabled when the remote no longer matches. I need to use local db's ident as the conidtion.  e.g. update local set status = 'disabled' where ident = '1'.

I am able to compare the hashes with positive results using the code below.

```
use strict;

my %remote_hash = (
    ident    => '1001',
    name     => 'remote hash name',
);
my %local_hash  = (
    ident         => '1',
    remote_ident  => '1001',
    name          => 'remote hash name',  
    status        => 'active'
);

foreach (sort keys %local_hash){
    unless (exists $remote_hash{$_}){
        print "$_: not found in Remote hash\n";
        next; 
    }
}
```

But, I do not understand how to use the code to pull out the ident for updating the db entry.  One of the method's I've tried, and what seemed to make the most sense to me was:

```
foreach my $test (sort keys %local_hash){
    unless (exists $remote_hash{$_}){
        print "$_: not found in Remote hash\n";
        print $test{ident};
        next; 
    }
}
```

With this, I will receive the following error: Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
Additionally, if I don't call the ident, and run the code as:

```
foreach my $test (sort keys %local_hash){
    unless (exists $remote_hash{$_}){
        print "$_: not found in Remote hash\n";
        next; 
    }
}
```

It breaks the whole thing, and sees all records as a mismatch.
I am not sure how to approach this further.  Can some one assist me in the direction to correct the problem I am having?

---

Edit - In reply to simbabque.  I think I made a gross misrepresentation of the hashes.
Here is a better breakdown of the hashes in question.

When dumping the remote hash, this what I get.

```
$VAR1 = '1001';
$VAR2 = 'NAME 1';
$VAR3 = '1002';
$VAR4 = 'NAME 2';
$VAR5 = '1003';
$VAR6 = 'NAME 3';
$VAR7 = '1004';
$VAR8 = 'NAME 4';
$VAR9 = '1005';
```

When dumping the local hash, I get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'ident'             => '1',
            'group_name'            => 'NAME 1',
            'status'        => 'active',
            'unique_id'             => '1001',
          },
```

For the remote hash I turned an array into a hash by doing the following:

```
my %remote_hash;
foreach my $data_pair( @remote_hash_list){
    my $ident = $data_pair->{ident};
    my $group_name = $data_pair->{sched_group};
       $group_name =~ s/\s+$//g;

    $remote_hash{$ident} = $group_name;
}
```

I am kinda of winging this, so I am not sure if this is even the right method of turning an array into a hash.  If I dump the array @remote_hash_list I get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ident'       => 1001,
          'sched_group' => 'NAME 1',
        };
```

When I tried the method you've explained, the $hash{value}; is empty.
I assume though, this has to do with how the hashes are built?

Comment: hard to understand what you are trying to do; do you want to determine if there are any differences between the two hashes in keys other than ident and status?  Or maybe just ident?

Comment: All I want to see is whether the unique_ident I have recorded in the local db is seen in the remote hash. If not, regardless of the whether any other information matches, disable the record on the local database.  This is because, if the ident changes in the remote, a new record is created for it in the local db.  Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: just to be clear, is the dump of the remote hash you show a dump of @remote_hash_list or of %remote_hash?  and are you creating %remote_hash just for the lookup this question involves, or do you also need it for other purposes?

Comment: (as an aside, when dumping hashes or arrays, you get better output if you dump a reference to them - e.g. `Dumper( \%remote_hash )` so they aren't flattened into a list first.)

Comment: the dump is of @remote_hash_list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- you are iterating over a list of keys and you put each key in `$test`, but you are looking at `$_`; that variable is not used in your loop. It probably has old data.
- you are using the scalar `$test` (which is one of the keys from `%local_hash`) as another hash.

What you want to do is look at the remote key `ident` after you have compared your hashes.

According to your description of the problem, all you need to do is this:

```
if ($local_hash{status} ne $remote_hash{status}){
  update( $remote_hash{ident}, $remote_hash{status} );
}
```

For those two hashes you do not even need a loop.

If you have a bunch of hashes, you would do that in a loop over the hashes, like the result of your remote query.

Comment: When attempting your method, the hashref is always empty. This is my fault, as I think I made a gross misrepresentation of the hashes.  I've included a better description of the hashes in the original question.